# A decision problem that is Cook-reducible to its complement

Tags: computer-science, np-complete, decision-problems

I'm taking an algorithms course and we are covering polynomial time reductions, and I've read online that many decision problems are polynomial-time reducible to their complements.

Can anyone give me an example of one such decision problem?

I tried to reduce the Composite decision problem to Prime, but don't really know how to go about it.

Comment: I did a Google search for "decision problems are polynomial-time reducible to their complements" and got a number of hits. Some of them look promising.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to polynomial-time reduce an instance of the COMPOSITE decision problem to the PRIME decision problem.

1. Consider an instance of COMPOSITE in the form of a number $n$.
2. In polynomial time, determine if $n$ is prime (using the [AKS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)).
3. If $n$ is prime, let $m = 4$, otherwise let $m = 2$.
4. $m$ is the corresponding instance of PRIME.